# iText - data from a resultset

Tags: itext

I have a few resultsets in java and now I have to create a PdF with itext from them.

What is the best way to start to retrieve the data.

Because a resultset is a table I whas thinking of filling in a table.  Or is there a better, standard way.

This is the first time I use iText so I have no idea where to start.

thx all

Comment: perhaps start here: http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thw : perhaps start here: itextpdf.com/examples did the trick